# driver asus mb168b ubuntu 18.10

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors

Since there is no official driver for this usb monitor, i download 
[https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu][1]
But there is no driver for 18.10 ubuntu version , i'm even able to build and install, but there are some problems: 
1)When usb monitor works, laptop monitor lags.
2)In orizontal mode it works only if my laptop monitor is 4:3.
In vertical mode instead it works fine.

Anyone who has the same problem?